# Regular expression for replacing html ampersand with xml equivalent

Tags: c#, regex

How can I write a c# regular expression to use for replacing an ampersand (&) with consideration that the ampersand occurrence could be in & > © or AT&T

For example... Regex.Replace("(\S)&(\S![^;])", "$1&$2");

Comment: Why don't you just html/xml encode?

Comment: I'm building an xhtml parser for mobile web. I get html from a cms and then parse it to be xhtml compliant. Will the solution you propose help in anyway?

Comment: Indeed it will, take a look at my posted answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To directly replace `"&"` with `"&amp;` you don't need a regex, just use `String.Replace` (or `StringBuilder.Replace`).

However to replace `"&"` where it isn't followed by a `"amp;"` does need a regex, and a "[Zero-width negative lookahead assertion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx#grouping_constructs)":<sup>1</sup>

```
var result = Regex.Replace(input, "&(?!amp;)", "&amp;");
```

<sup>1</sup> The reason to use a *zero-width* assertion is to handle `"&"` at the end of the string.

Comment: I could but the problem with replace is that it will replace for example, Boys&amp;Girls with &, causing it to be Boys&amp;amp;Girls which is not what I want.

Comment: @Michael: I thought that might be the case... but a solution that replaces `&` not followed by `amp;` will always do that, even if you want to show `&amp;` in the document. I'll revise shortly. I suggest you update the Q to be more specific.

Comment: Ok now understood that, you can replace &amp; to some specific character/string like {theampchar} then replace & to &amp; and {theampchar} to &amp; again.

Comment: but what about other escaped characters like &gt; &lt;

Comment: @baalazamon Out of scope of the question.

Answer (score 3):

You could use regex like: `"&(?!(amp)|(lt)|(apos)|(gt)|(quot);)`

Comment: That wouldn't work, 'cause all you did was to match an ampersand followed by anything that isn't `a`, `m`, `p` or `;`

Comment: I've fixed it it will do negative lookahead (?!...) for grouped words like amp, lt and skip them

Comment: A regular expression as the op wants would be too complex, 'cause we're forgetting the cases `&#00` and so forth

Answer (score 1):

I would propose that you just [HtmlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73z22y6h.aspx) it:

```
System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode()
```

Comment: This what gets displayed on my web page when using the htmlencode method: <h1><strong>MoMo #10: Futuristic view on Mobility<br /></strong></h1>

Comment: Well, that's because you have html encoded it? Don't encode the html